# I need to break lines in a {tabular} environment using memoir

Tags: tables, line-breaking, memoir

I need this table to fit the page...breaking the lines...
Is there a way to do it?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} %=========================================================================


\[ \textbf{ONDAS CEREBRAIS}\]

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
    ONDA   & FREQUÊNCIA    & EFEITO                                                   \\
    Gama   & 22 a 50 C/S   & Estado emocional                                         \\
    Betha  & 14 a 21 C/S   & Estado de vigília, comum à maioria das pessoas despertas \\
    Alfa   & 8 a 13 C/S    & Sonolência – relax                                       \\
    Tetha  & 4 a 7 C/S     & Sono relax profundo                                      \\
    Deltha & 0,5 a 3,5 C/S & Sono profundo  transe hipnótico
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried to  use some info from [http://tinyurl.com/hmvswju] with  no success.

Answer (score 1):

This break text in the last line:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    ONDA   & FREQUÊNCIA    & EFEITO                                                   \\
    Gama   & 22 a 50 C/S   & Estado emocional                                         \\
    Betha  & 14 a 21 C/S   & Estado de vigília, comum à maioria das pessoas despertas \\
    Alfa   & 8 a 13 C/S    & Sonolência – relax                                       \\
    Tetha  & 4 a 7 C/S     & Sono relax profundo                                      \\
    Deltha & 0,5 a 3,5 C/S & Sono profundo  transe hipnótico
\end{tabularx}
```

however result is fragile: you have small paper size (a5), big font size (14pt), so the table occupy almost whole page:

[image]

For use above code sniped you need to add `\usepackage{tabularx}` into preamble of your document. For testing of result I also add `\usepackage{showframe}` which in production of document had to be removed.

Comment: What exatcly does this `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` do?
`\raggedright` is for alignment.
`\arraybackslash}X` is for what?

Comment: The best way to see importance of `\arraybackslash` is not use it (in test)  :-). Seriously (and shortly), it preserve meaning of \\ on the end of row. Actually it is necessary only in the last cell in the row, but for convenience is the best to use always when you define new column type or local defining aligning of text in cells (as is the case in my answer).

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm.
Thanks @Zarko.
Do you know if there is way to have a bigger vertical spacing between lines?

Comment: vertical spacing you can change with `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` where `1.2` increase streatch for 20%. With select this number you can adjust it according to your wish.

Comment: And will it be globally set? or just in this specific table

Comment: Depend, where you will declare it. In preamble is **global**, with `{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} \begin{tabularx}{...} {...} ... \end{tabularx}}˙will set stretch locally for table inside curly braces. –